# make: *** No rule to make target `under'. Stop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, linux-mint

I am very new to linux. I am following what my teacher said on his webpage. The command I have to type to compile is  make under ./cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src. And So I put make under /home/dkk/cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src. and It give me error that make: *** No rule to make target `under'.  Stop. I am running linux mint 14. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to guess you're supposed to enter the ./cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src directory and then type `make` without arguments. That is, `make`, *under* ./cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying you should type:

```
make under /home/dkk/cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src
```

It's saying you should change to that directory and type `make`:

```
cd /home/dkk/cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src
make
```

Or equivalently:

```
make -C /home/dkk/cbp2-infrastructure-v2/src
```

Comment: great! thank you very much. Can I ask you for one more favor? How can I run the compiled file from the terminal? when I tried to run it by typing run traces under -C /home/dkk/cbp2-infrastructure-v2/ it says run: command not found. Am I typing the write command? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, that means "go to that directory and type `traces`".  You should probably ask your teacher or a classmate for help - it seems like you need a very basic tutorial.

Comment: oh okay thanks. The assignment pdf says that I should type run traces under ./cbp2-infrastructure-v2/ what should i type to run the program. I know I need basic tutorial,but can you please tell me if there is any command I need to type to run the program? thank you

Comment: oh actually I got it. I just needed to change directory to the folder containing the file and type g++ predict where predict is the name of the program. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.